# "Vertex attribute locations are always 4-component", Does that mean that i can use mat2 as vertex attribute without any problems?? (OpenGL)

Tags: opengl, glsl

I know that vertex attribute locations are always 4-component, but i am not entirely sure that it applies to mat2(and other mat2 types) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "without any problems".

Yes, `mat2` is a valid type for a vertex attribute. However, [when used as attributes](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Multiple_attributes), *all* matrix types are treated as arrays of the columns of the matrix. And arrays are treated such that each array element is a separate attribute.

So a `mat2` counts as *two* attributes, not one (specifically the first two components of each attribute). If that's not a problem for you, then you may do that.

If you want to stuff a `mat2` into one attribute, then you have to do it manually:

```
layout(location = X) in vec4 matrix_attrib;
...
void main()
{
  mat4 mAttrib(matrix_attrib.xy, matrix_attrib.zw);
}
```

Comment: By that i mean, you should not have to do extra work on cpu to set each row of 4x4 matrix separatly.

Comment: thanks for the answer, exactly what i needed.

Comment: this row column thing is confusing, some people call it inversed.

Comment: @NameThatDisplays: It's not confusing; [people just explain it wrong](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/18929/8240).

Comment: I know, thats why it's confusing, people are tought wrong and teach wrong, am not even sure if i use them correctly.